# Shortening the length of SearchView on Toolbar in Android

Tags: android, xml, android-toolbar, searchview

I'm trying to shorten the length of the `SearchView` once I click on the search icon because it is colliding with my `ImageView` logo as you can see here:

[image]

I want it to stay like this when not in focus:

[image]

I would like for the `SearchView` to expand up to the end of the `ImageView` logo.
Here is my toolbar code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/outnix_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:src="@drawable/outnix_logo_big"/>


</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

The Menu items code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/preferences_menu_item"
        android:title="@string/preferences"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/sign_in_menu_item"
        android:title="@string/sign_in"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/search_menu_item"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/searchview"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="@string/search"/>

</menu>
```

And the `SearchView` code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</android.support.v7.widget.SearchView>
```

I tried changing the `layout_width` of `SearchView` to 200dp instead of `match_parent` but this is what happened:

[image]

I would like for the search icon to stay on the right side (before the overflow menu icon) but expand the length of the `SearchView` right before the logo. Is this possible? If yes, any help is appreciated!

Comment: Just change width of search view

Comment: @Don'tBenegative What do you mean? I showed what happens when you change the `layout_width`. It doesn't work like I want to.

Comment: can you add margin left = "80dp" of `searchview`.. see if this works

Comment: @Kool I tried that along with `margin_start` and neither worked. It stayed exactly the same as my first picture :/

Answer (score 0):

**Just add a Id to Image view and search view**

add this extra line in search view 
`android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageviewl"`

Use Your Search view like this
Keep an Id to Image View

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/outnix_toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:src="@drawable/outnix_logo_big"/>
```

and change your search view to this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageviewl"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">
</android.support.v7.widget.SearchView>
```

Comment: I tried it, it didn't change anything. Looks exactly like the first picture. Thanks for the try though!

Comment: try `wrap_content` insted of `match_parent` if possible post your screen after trying this

Comment: I did, same thing :/ I would post it if anything changed but it looks exactly like the first picture.